# No speex packages for freeswitch building on Ubuntu

Tags: 12.04, apt, compiling, configure

I am trying to build `freeswitch` on Ubuntu and getting numerous libraries absent. One of them is `speex`. `configure` says it is absent while `dpkg` says it is here:

```
checking for speex >= 1.2rc1 speexdsp >= 1.2rc1... Package speex was not found in the pkg-config search path. Perhaps you should add the directory containing `speex.pc' to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable No package 'speex' found Package speexdsp was not found in the pkg-config search path. Perhaps you should add the directory containing `speexdsp.pc' to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable No package 'speexdsp' found
configure: error: Library requirements (speex >= 1.2rc1 speexdsp >= 1.2rc1) not met; consider adjusting the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable if your libraries are in a nonstandard prefix so pkg-config can find them.
dims@nebula2:~/src/freeswitch$ dpkg -l *speex*
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name                             Version                          Description
+++-================================-================================-================================================================================
ii  libspeex1                        1.2~rc1-3ubuntu2                 The Speex codec runtime library
ii  libspeexdsp1                     1.2~rc1-3ubuntu2                 The Speex extended runtime library
ii  speex                            1.2~rc1-3ubuntu2                 The Speex codec command line tools
```

why? and how to fix?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to install `libspeex-dev`

```
sudo apt-get install libspeex-dev
```

So, you will have below result :

```
saman@jack:~$ dpkg -l *speex*
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name           Version      Architecture Description
+++-==============-============-============-=================================
ii  libspeex-dev:a 1.2~rc1.1-1u amd64        The Speex codec library developme
ii  libspeex1:amd6 1.2~rc1.1-1u amd64        The Speex codec runtime library
ii  libspeexdsp1:a 1.2~rc1.1-1u amd64        The Speex extended runtime librar
un  speex          <none>       <none>       (no description available)
```

Comment: How would I know that?

Comment: Did you try that?

Comment: Yes, but in general, how would I know library names if they different?

Answer (score 8):

You may also need to install the `libspeexdsp-dev` package (which depends on `libspeex-dev`):

```
sudo apt-get install libspeexdsp-dev
```